# Insert data to database not working (PHP-SQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-insert, insert-into

My insert data sql command in my PHP code is not working. Can anyone help please?

I have a registration form that takes the values from the input fields (name, lastname, email, username and password)

The values that the user inputs in this fields should be saved into my table "users" whith columns (ID [which is the primary key /INT], name [TEXT], lastname[TEXT], e-mail [VARCHAR], username[VARCHAR] and password [VARCHAR]) .

Here is my current code:

```php
if (isset ($_POST['name'],$_POST['lastname'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
    {
        //connect to database
        $conn = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', '', 'test_database');

        if ($conn)          
        {
            $sql="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_POST['username'] . "';";
            $query = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);
            $result = mysqli_fetch_array ($query);

            if ($result ['username'])
            {
                header ('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?errno=1');
            }
            else
            {
                $sql="INSERT INTO users (ID, name, lastname, e-mail, username, password) VALUES (' ','" .$_POST['name'] . "' ,'" . $_POST['lastname']. "' ,'" . $_POST['email']. "' ,'" . $_POST['username']. "' ,'" . $_POST['password']. "');";
                mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);
                mysqli_close ($conn);   
                //registration completed, redirect to index page
                //header ('Location:index.php?reg=1');

            }
        }

        else
        {
            echo 'connection error';
        }

    }
```

Comment: [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) give you anything? Also, your code is very exposed to SQL-injection: you should start using prepared statements with placeholders to avoid this exposure.

Comment: Because you are inserting space into primary key `VALUES (' ',`

Comment: Hi thank you for the quick reply and thank you for the advice. I am just starting to learn sql and php so this is more of a start excercise for me but will consider to look up what you said. No errors are showing. I have looked for pother similar posts to this and most of them relate to the use of the quotes...so here is what my $sql variable prints as an example: INSERT INTO users (ID, name, lastname, e-mail, username, password) VALUES (' ','Bill' ,'Gates' ,'bill.gates@microsoft.com' ,'bill' ,'bill01');

Comment: As Saty have pointed out, you are inserting a space as your primary ID. Your ID field is most likely set to "auto increment" which means that you can simply omit it from the insert completely, `INSERT .... (name, ....) VALUES('JOHN', ....` Like so.

Comment: Thank you, i removed the space and is still not working. I have also tried to type NULL for the value instead of using an empty sting for the ID column but still no success. Also tried to remove the ID from the insert and still not working (both column and value)

Comment: Did you remove it from both parts? I mean both from the column list and the values list?

Comment: Yes. Not working yet

Comment: is your ID field set to auto increment? If not, then you might want to consider doing so.

Comment: it is. Not working yet --> IDPrimary int(255)   No None AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Echo the query and copy it, then try and execute it directly in phpmyadmin, see if it throws any errors there.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now, the error was at 'e-mail' field it didn't like the dash -. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides what has already been outlined in comments for the space `VALUES (' ',` for the `ID` column etc., your email column name contains a hyphen and is interpreted as `e` **MINUS** `mail` and as a mathematical operation.

Either rename it to `e_mail` or place ticks around it.

```
`e-mail`
```

Read the following on Identifier Qualifiers:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Having used `mysqli_error($conn)` on the query would have thrown you a syntax error.

Sidenote: You should be escaping your data for quite a few reasons, one is for protection against an SQL injection and if your data could contain characters that MySQL could complain about such as `John's Bar & Grill` as an example.

---

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

**Important sidenote about column length:**

If and when you do decide to use `password_hash()` or crypt, it is important to note that if your present password column's length is anything lower than 60, it will need to be changed to that (or higher). The manual suggests a length of 255.

You will need to ALTER your column's length and start over with a new hash in order for it to take effect. Otherwise, MySQL will fail silently.

Comment: Am on mobile right now so I was not able to show ticks. I will improve my answer in a few minutes

Comment: Ah, I was staring myself blind on that bloody query, nicely spotted.

Comment: @Epodax hoping that is all that is wrong. Let's see what the op has to say

Comment: _"Thank you so much! It works now, the error was at 'e-mail' field it didn't like the dash -. Thank you! "_ - Spot on.

Comment: yeah thanks as i wrote in the comment that was the error. I put the command directly into the sql console and it showed me that. SO thanks to the both of you and sorry for the extended comments

Comment: @Epodax I saw that above in comments when I was mobile. I'm on my PC now *lol* and also improved on my answer. *Cheers*

Comment: OMG it is hyphen. Nice catch @Fred-ii- !!

Comment: @Saty Yeah, that'll put a damper on someone's day for sure.

Answer (score 0):

you use ' ' to insert id. the id should be autoincrement and unique. you cannot insert a white space to all.
try to remove id from insert into query. turn your query into this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users (name, lastname, e-mail, username, password) VALUES ('" .$_POST['name'] . "' ,'" . $_POST['lastname']. "' ,'" . $_POST['email']. "' ,'" . $_POST['username']. "' ,'" . $_POST['password']. "');";
```